# repeating items in relativelayout, how to clean this approach?

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout, repeat

hello i have lot of categories like this (more than 8 xml layouts) and they got the same structure, like this

[image]

here is an example of the category_architecture.xml from my layout folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_architecture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/category_architecture_background">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_architecture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_architecture" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_architecture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_architecture"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView_architecture"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_architecture"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/architecture"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_building"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_architecture"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/switch_building"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_building" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_building"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_building"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_architecture"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_building"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:text="@string/building"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch_building"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_building"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView_building"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_architecture" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_bridge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_building"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/switch_building"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_bridge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_bridge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_bridge"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_building"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_building"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:text="@string/bridge"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch_bridge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView_monument"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_building"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_architecture" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_monument"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_bridge"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/switch_building"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_monument" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_monument"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView_airport"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_building"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_bridge"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:text="@string/Monument"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch_monument"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_monument"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_bridge"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_architecture" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch_airport"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_airport"
        android:layout_below="@+id/switch_monument"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_architecture" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_airport"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_monument"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/switch_building"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_airport" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_airport"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_airport"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_building"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_monument"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:text="@string/airport"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch_park_attraction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_park_attraction"
        android:layout_below="@+id/switch_airport"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_architecture" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_park_attraction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_airport"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/switch_building"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_amusement" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_park_attraction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_park_attraction"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_building"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView_park_attraction"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:text="@string/amusment"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch_infrastructure"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_infrastructure"
        android:layout_below="@+id/switch_park_attraction"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_architecture" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_infrastructure"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_park_attraction"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/switch_building"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_infrastructure" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_infrastructure"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_infrastructure"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_building"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_park_attraction"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:text="@string/infrastructure"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

so i have some questions relative to this layout implementation :

1. Is that a good choice to put this into a relative layout?
2. Is there a way to reduce code redundancies?
3. May i use some listView?
4. Compared to LinearLayout, what is better to use?
5. What should be your approach to make this kind of things?

The layout implementation is ok, all is working (switch listeners, picutre changing on searchview when trigger a line, appbar icon switching according to category and colors of searchview and appbar also...

But i think there's lot of tips to avoid getting so much repetitive code... It was a lot of work to do all the categories layouts, and i want to be sure of what im doing before changing my main approach... ( i dont wanna spend hours beating around the bush without any correct results...)

P.S : i'm sorry for begging here, but i wanna collect some external advice in order to improve my code and learning this for my future work, thanks ;)

Comment: Read more about [include and merge](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html). That is if you don't want to use them on a list, but using a list could work too I think.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should use a RecyclerView (or ListView).
Try to see your layout as a list with different cell layouts : "nature header", "nature cell", "geography header"...
Then, with a normal RecyclerView mechanism it should be straight forward.

This explained example will help you :

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView

Comment: i already tried with recyclerview but i was lost, i use recyclerview to store my search results and display them but i dont know how to do with defined items like it :(

Comment: Keep going this way, start with what you have for your search results. Then you'll need to create several layouts for your types of cells, several holders, then use the type of your data to pick the right layout and right holder depending on the position.